# Проблема с использованием кнопок (клавиатуры) в программе

Tags: c, borland

Ответьте, пожалуйста, на вопрос. Мне необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на стрелочки выполнялся переход курсора по массиву (окну с текстом). Если нажата стрелочка вверх, то перемещение на позицию вверх и так далее. Пользуюсь функцией `gotoxy`. Сама суть проблемы в том, что программа не принимает нажатие этих кнопок (стрелок), а просто печатает заглавные буквы вместо действий как будто я тупо текст ввожу. По нажатию на стрелочки, которые программировал должны происходить конкретные действия прописанные в коде... Лишь печатает например K M в соответствии с определенной клавишей. Почему такой сбой? Где путаница?

```
      gotoxy(1,1);
      i=1;
      j=1;
      while(z != 'z')
      {

        ch=getch();
        if(ch==27)
        {z='z';}
        if(ch==38)
         {
           if (i>1) i--;
           gotoxy(j, i);
         }
        if(ch==39)
             {
           if (j>=1) j++;
           gotoxy(j, i);
         }
        if(ch==40)
         {
           if (i>=1) i++;
           gotoxy(j, i);
         }
        if(ch==37)
         {
           if (j>1) j--;
           gotoxy(j, i);
         }
        putchar(ch);

      }
```

Comment: стрелки кодируются двумя символами, вы читаете только один, дебагером воспользуйтесь, посмотрите что у вас за код при нажатии стрелки идет...

Comment: как им пользоваться? вы можете подсказать где скачивать его? и какой именно нужен!

Comment: он должен быть в среде по идее, что-то типа Debug (хотя может и не было его тогда, в вашем 92-м году)... Можно запустить вот такой код:

    while (1) {
      int i=getch();
      printf("%d\n",i);
    }

понажимать стрелки и последить за выводом.

Answer (score 1):

вопрос потерял свою актуальность! я сделал сам)) спасибо всем !кому интересно вот:

```
 while(z != 'z')
      {

        ch=getch();

    if(ch==27)
        {z='z';}
        else if(ch==72)
         {
           if (i>1) i--;
           gotoxy(j, i);
         }
        else if(ch==77)
             {
           if (j>=1) j++;
           gotoxy(j, i);
         }
        else if(ch==80)
         {
           if (i>=1) i++;
           gotoxy(j, i);
         }
        else if(ch==75)
         {
           if (j>1) j--;
           gotoxy(j, i);
         }
        else
        putchar(ch);

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо if-ов использовать switch

Answer (score 0):

Горе в том, что getch() при нажиманию стрелок (и другие спец-клавиши) сначала кидает 0, а потом код. По-этому, если словили 0, следующий байт скажет о клавише. Стрелки ловим вот-так:

```
switch(getch()) 
    {
        case 0 :
            switch(getch())
            {
                case 80 : /*down*/ break;
                case 72 : /*up*/ break;
                case 77 : /*right*/ break;
                case 75 : /*left*/ break;
                case 45 : /* alt + X */ break;
            } break;
        case 13 : /*enter*/ break;
        case 27 : /*escape*/ break;
    }
```

Comment: ну где же вы были пару дней назад_) спасибо))

Comment: на киберфоруме, наверное :)